# Hierarchical layering in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a set of employee data similar to:

```
var users = new[] 
{
   new {SupervisorId = "CEO", UserId = "CEO", UserName = "Joe"},
   new {SupervisorId = "CEO", UserId = "CIO", UserName = "Mary"},
   new {SupervisorId = "CIO", UserId = "XDIR", UserName = "Ed"},
   new {SupervisorId = "CIO", UserId = "YDIR", UserName = "Lisa"},
   new {SupervisorId = "XDIR", UserId = "AMNGR", UserName = "Steve"},
   new {SupervisorId = "AMNGR", UserId = "ASUP", UserName = "Lesley"}
};
```

Would it be possible to use Linq to add hierarchical layers, in the sense that:

- CEO = 1 (top)
- CIO = 2 (2nd level)
- XDIR and YDIR = 3 (3rd level)
- AMNGR = 4 (etc)
- ASUP = 5 (etc)

I've been able to group the employees according to SupervisorId, but not sure how to make the "level" happen.

```
var userGroups = from user in users
  group user by user.SupervisorId into userGroup
  select new
  {
    SupervisorId = userGroup.Key,
    Level = ??????
    Users = userGroup.ToList()
  };

  foreach (var group in userGroups)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", group.SupervisorId, group.Level, group.Users.Count);
  }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want the level to be the level applied to all members of the group.  If you look at group CEO then there a 2 levels with that.

Comment: @Leom, the CEO supervisorid is redundant, CEO supervisor = CEO.  So the idea is that where SupervisorId = UserId, you are CEO - the tree starts there.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a ranking to your linq "user object"

```
public class User{

  public string SupervisorId  {get;set;}
  public string UserId {get;set;}
  public string UserName   {get;set;}
  public int Level {get {  return GetRank(SupervisorId  ) ; } } 

  private int GetRank(string userId){
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)){
         //Bad case, probably want to use a very large number
         return -1;
     }
     int level = 0;
     switch(userId){
        case "CEO":
           level  = 0;
           break;

         //insert others here

     }

  }
}
```

Then your Linq you would add a join.

```
     var userGroups = from user in users
                     join super in users on user.SupervisorId  equals super.UserId
                     group user by  user.SupervisorId into userGroup 
                     select new
    {
        SupervisorId = userGroup.Key,
        Level =  super.Level, 
        Users = userGroup.ToList()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Heres one way to create a lookup table for each level. Its fairly and I dont know how it will scale. Obviously, you'll need to adapt it to pull the rows from your database.

Define a class to hold our lookup table

```
public class user{
    public string SupervisorId;
    public string UserId;   
    public int Level;
}
```

Then we get a unique list of UserId/SupervisorId combinations and loop through the list calculating the level for each combination by 'walking' up the tree.

```
    var uniqueusers = (new user[] 
        {
            new user {SupervisorId = "CEO", UserId = "CEO"},
            new user {SupervisorId = "CEO", UserId = "CIO"},
            new user {SupervisorId = "CIO", UserId = "XDIR"},
            new user {SupervisorId = "CIO", UserId = "YDIR"},
            new user {SupervisorId = "XDIR", UserId = "AMNGR"},
            new user {SupervisorId = "AMNGR", UserId = "ASUP"}
        }).Distinct();


        foreach (var item in uniqueusers)
        {           
            int level = 0;
            user CurrentUser = item;
            while (CurrentUser.UserId != CurrentUser.SupervisorId){
                CurrentUser = uniqueusers.Where(c => c.UserId == CurrentUser.SupervisorId).FirstOrDefault();
                level++;
            } 
            item.Level = level;             
        }
```

Now you can use the uniqueusers as a lookup table to determine the level for your query. eg

```
private int GetLevel(string userId){         
     return uniqueusers.Where(c => c.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault().Level;    
  }
```

You could probably even combine this into a single step with a little effort.

Comment: Same problem as stated above...the results are actually from a database and I can't hardcode any kind of layering.  The code needs to be able to infer the level based upon the idea that:
1) the CEO is the top node, where supervisorID - userID, and
2) every layer underneath is defined by supervisorID, ex., if your supervisor is CEO, then you are level 2, and so on...

Comment: Let me correct that second statement, if your supervisor is CEO and your userid is CEO, then you are CEO. but it works for every level underneath as stated above.

Comment: This looks VERY promising!  I'll give it a try today.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
ILookup<string, User> subordLookup = users
  .ToLookup(u => u.SupervisorId);

foreach(User user in users)
{
  user.Subordinates = subordLookup[user.UserId].ToList();
}

User userHierarchy = user.Single(u => u.UserId == "CEO");
```

Disclaimers:

- Does not handle multiple CEOs.
- Preserves circular relationships.
- Leaves orphans behind.

Comment: I don't currently have a User type defined.  Can you maybe explain how I would go about implementing that?

Comment: I'm going to try to implement User as a new class with the properities defined above and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
         var levels = new[]
        {
            new { Level = 1, LevelName = "CEO" },
            new { Level = 2, LevelName = "CIO" },
            new { Level = 3, LevelName = "XDIR" },
            new { Level = 3, LevelName = "YDIR" },
            new { Level = 4, LevelName = "AMNGR" },
            new { Level = 5, LevelName = "ASUP" }
        };                        

        var userGroups = from user in users
                         join level in levels on
                         user.UserId equals level.LevelName                             
                         group new{ User = user, Level = level.Level } by new { SuperId = user.SupervisorId, Level = level.Level } into userGroup
                         select new
                            {
                                SupervisorId = userGroup.Key.SuperId,
                                Level = userGroup.Key.Level,
                                Users = userGroup.ToList()
                            };
```

Comment: The problem is that I am retrieving this values form a database.  The code for object users is just an example.  My database only contains the users ID and the supervisor ID, and I need to be able to INFER the hierarchy from that - using CEO as the root.